# What is remote repositories ? and master branch?

Tags: git

I upload PHP website project to server godaddy. And I use Netbeans and once I code on project at localhost, it'll execute remote synchronization with project on server when I save file.

Now I want use Git, I read many guide, almost use GitHub. But I don't want to use GitHub.  And here :

http://progit.org/book/ch2-9.html

> To be able to collaborate on any Git project, you need to know how to manage your remote repositories.
>   Remote repositories are versions of your project that are hosted on the Internet or network somewhere

or

> Pushing to a Remote Server

- is Remote repositories is project on godaddy server ?
- And a more question:
  I only has 2 project code :

  - 1 on godaddy server,
  - 2 on localhost.
    Master branch is project code on my localhost in this case ?

I read many guide but almost don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

"Remote Repositories" is any git repo on a remote server where Git is installed.
GitHub is an example of "remote repos" server.

Should you want to deploy your PHP site directly through Git on your remote server (here a GoDaddy server), you need to make sure:

- Git is installed there
- you have a bare repo copied there
- you have the right hooks to deploy your website on each `git push`

See "[Deploy PHP using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-php-using-git)" or "[Git and PHP Deployment Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716655/git-and-php-deployment-tools)"

---

`master` is the branch usually checked out by default when cloning, but [this is not always the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015530/git-clone-does-not-bring-master-branch).
It is however a good practice to reserve the `master` branch for "what is running in production".

Comment: why the "good practice ... running in production"?  Convention or there is a technical reason?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: pure convention, but `master` is also *usually* the branch you get by default when cloning your bare repo from the prod remote workstation, so if you need to make a patch in an hurry, you can start right away.