# Change master to Rails 3 branch in GIT?

Tags: git, merge, branch, push, git-push

I currently have the following structure in my GIT repository:

```
// LOCAL
   /master
   /rails3 (HEAD)

// REMOTE
   /HEAD
   /master
   /rails3
```

I am not sure why the remote (GitHub in this case) has a HEAD branch and the local version doesn't.

I am trying to workout what how to switch the Rails3 branch to be master and rename the master branch to be called Rails2. I am using Tower for Mac which has a rename option for the local branches but I am concerned what will happen if I then push that branch to the master.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Danny

**UPDATE**

```
  git branch -a

  MacBook:BaseApp2 danny$ git branch -a
  master
* rails3
  remotes/beanstalk/master
  remotes/beanstalk/rails3
  remotes/heroku/master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/rails3
```

Comment: So as I say in my answer; `HEAD -> origin/master` doesn't mean your remote GitHub repo has a branch named '`HEAD`', it is a **symbolic reference** to the `remote` master branch. So you need to rename `remote/master` as shown in the link I propose below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `git branch -a` displays for you?

I have for instance:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

meaning HEAD isn't a branch, but a pointer (commit) to the remote master branch.

To change the branch referenced by HEAD (and rename master on the GitHub side), see:

"[How do I change a Git remote HEAD to point to something besides “master”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485578/how-do-i-change-a-git-remote-head-to-point-to-something-besides-master)"

Comment: (the solution is a bit similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015530/git-clone-does-not-bring-master-branch)

Comment: Results of 'git branch -a' have been added to my question.